Solve conflicting getter definitions for property in Jackson
I have the following class:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Options {
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private Value valueObj;
}

I see the following error while using Jackson:
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "value": Options#getValue() vs Options#getValueObj()

My JSON is like this:
{
    "behaviors": [
        {
            "name": "dnsAsyncRefresh",
            "options": {
                "enabled": true,
                "timeout": "1h",
                "value": {
                    "id": "1234"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "timeout",
            "options": {
                "value": "5s"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I am using the same Options class to map all the options in my JSON.
